# Via the api, can I force the user to login to reddit?

Tags: webview, oauth, uwp, credentials, reddit

I am writing a Reddit client that uses OAuth to authenticate the user. One of the features I would like to implement is the ability to use multiple accounts simultaneously. This requires the user to authorize my client on each account they want to use. The problem I'm running into is that if the user is already logged into Reddit in their browser, when I pop a browser to perform the auth, it will have them authenticate my client against their currently logged in user.

Is there a way to force the user to re-enter their credentials? I would rather not have to put some kind of disclaimer on my Add Account screen that says "Please log out of Reddit in any open browser windows".

I tried opening the Reddit login page in a WebView so the request is sandboxed, and while that worked, it gives the user access to the entire login page (including all the links that navigate to elsewhere on the site). I don't mind that experience when I'm popping an external browser, but in an embedded WebView I really just want to present a username and password box along with the OAuth validation prompt.

Note: I do kind of prefer the embedded experience because it doesn't interfere with the users existing browser cookies, I just don't like how cluttered the login page is this way and I'm not sure how to prevent the user from navigating away from login. Also, for completeness, this is a UWP app, though this problem is largely technology independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem I'm running into is that if the user is already logged into Reddit in their browser, when I pop a browser to perform the auth, it will have them authenticate my client against their currently logged in user.

It may be caused by the authorization server. If so, we can not do anything in our client app.

But if it is not the server issue, in UWP, there is a [WebAuthenticationBroker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker) class witch can help you to authorize your app to access the user info from Resource server by getting a token. You can try to use the class to implement OAuth authorization. You don't need to use the in a WebView so that you can authorize your app with multiple users if you can manage all the user with the token properly in your code logic.

See the [Web authentication broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-authentication-broker) topic and the [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebAuthenticationBroker) to learn more details.

Comment: As far as forcing the login goes, this works perfectly! The user is still able to navigate around inside the pane that pops up due to the login page Reddit presents, but there's not much I can do about that client-side as far as I know.